# Adding image to toggle (hide / show) sidebar using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to add the image instead of  << to hide the left side bar, and right arrow >> to show the hidden side bar instead of showing same (<<) arrow

http://jsfiddle.net/6FMZY/449/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There: http://jsfiddle.net/M6xJT/

CSS:

```
.left {
    background: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/pixelmixer/basic/32/left-icon.png') no-repeat;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display:block;
}

.right {
    background: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/pixelmixer/basic/32/right-icon.png') no-repeat;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display:block;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#toggle').toggle(function(){
    $('#A').animate({width:0});
    $('#B').animate({left:0});

    $(this).removeClass('left').addClass('right');
},function(){
    $('#A').animate({width:200});
    $('#B').animate({left:200});

    $(this).removeClass('right').addClass('left');
})​;
```

​

Comment: Please post your code in your answer, even if OP did not do the same.

Comment: awesome... .. can you update the sidebar from left to right ...thanks in advance

Comment: Since `.right` is listed after `.left` in your CSS, it will override automatically. You don't need to remove or add the `left` class at all. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/M6xJT/1/

Comment: @Blazemonger You are right, but I don't like seeing a `<a href="" class"left right"></a>`. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @PHP It's not nice to change your question after someone has already answered what you originally posted. Work it out yourself, or please post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? Use `&larr;` and `&rarr;` in place of the word "Toggle":

```
$('#toggle').toggle(function(){
    $('#A').animate({width:0});
    $('#B').animate({left:0});
    $('#toggle').html('&rarr;');
},function(){
    $('#A').animate({width:200});
    $('#B').animate({left:200});
    $('#toggle').html('&larr;');
})​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/6FMZY/451/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#toggle').toggle(function(){
    $('#A').animate({width:0});
    $('#B').animate({left:0});
    $('#B > a').html('>>');
},function(){
    $('#A').animate({width:200});
    $('#B').animate({left:200});
    $('#B > a').html('<<');
})​
```

like this